# Python How to Bold the Text in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

Let me have your suggestion to bold the text and return in the following scenario,

```
 if is_duplicate is True:
            type = 'ORIGINAL COPY'+'\n'+'DUPLICATE COPY'+'\n'+'TRIPLICATE COPY'+'\n'+'QUADRUPLICATE COPY'
 return type
```

Sample output : I need to bold duplicate text, if is_duplicate is true.
ORIGINAL COPY 
**DUPLICATE COPY** 
TRIPLICATE COPY 
QUADRUPLICATE COPY

I have tried \033[1m this code in front of this text, but it couldn't workaround me. So Help me to fix this.

Comment: The text is to be rendered where?

Comment: This is to be printed in Report. Im using Aeroo Report for this. The design is carried out in Libreoffice odt format. I have to pass this string from .py file

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have started with '\033[1m' but haven't ended with '\033[0m'

```
if is_duplicate is True:
        type = 'ORIGINAL COPY'+'\n'+'\033[1m'+'DUPLICATE COPY'+ '\033[0m' +'\n'+'TRIPLICATE COPY'+'\n'+'QUADRUPLICATE COPY'
return type
```

Comment: Aeroo Reports: Error while generating the report "Print Form".

PCDATA invalid Char value 27, line 1, column 12195